# Angular conditional selection list dropdown not refreshing

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown lists, the values in list 2 depend on what's chosen in list 1.

Here's a watch on my list number 1 in controller:

```
$scope.$watch('customer.customerOccupation.industry', () => {
if ($scope.customer.customerOccupation.industry) {
    $scope.employmentIndustryTranslation = $translate.instant("customerOccupation." + $scope.customer.customerOccupation.industry);

    // here I check for what is the value and depending on that I assign possible values for list number 2
    if ($scope.customer.customerOccupation.industry.includes("arts")) {
        $scope.employment_occupation_legit = angular.copy($scope.art_employment_occupation_legit)
    } else if ($scope.customer.customerOccupation.industry.includes("leisure")) {
        $scope.employment_occupation_legit = [];
        $scope.employment_occupation_legit = angular.copy($scope.leisure_employment_occupation_legit)
    }
} 
})
```

The `scope.art_employment_occupation_legit` and `scope. leisure_employment_occupation_legit` are already there (obtained from DB)

Here is my template for the second list:

```
<div>
   <editable class="nopadding" type="select2"
      ng-bind="employmentOccupationTranslation"
      header="'customers.occupation' | translate"
      value="customer.customerOccupation.occupation"
      source="employment_occupation_legit"></editable>
</div>
```

Now, the problem is that the source for the dropdown `employment_occupation_legit`is not updated when I change the value for the first list. It refreshes to the correct one only when I refresh the page.
Any suggestions? I've tried to add $apply and timeout functions but somehow it didn't help